# Counting letters in each index of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of words. I would like to get the letter count to print next to each word. I get the words to print with a total of all letters to print at the end. Any guidance would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y3Oi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to print length of each word, below should work.

```
a = #[array of words]
a.each {|e| p "#{e} has #{e.length} letters"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = [] #array words
words.each {|w| puts "#{w} : #{w.length}"}
```

other way you can use Gem "words_counted" https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted for natural language processor